# Why does use.fontawesome.com CDN give me a CORS error?

Tags: javascript, cors, font-awesome

After putting my email address into https://cdn.fontawesome.com/ I've used the script they mailed me below successfully for a few weeks:

```
<script 
  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f77107.js"
  integrity="sha384-I95sGQCWfGLJRrRjoLq3cZ/yPbdj"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

but over the past few days I now get the error:

`Script from origin 'https://use.fontawesome.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

**How do I fix this?**

** **UPDATE** **

Here is the network request in Chrome for the script:

```
Request URL:https://use.fontawesome.com/f7710.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:198.232.124.196:443
Response Headers
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:text/javascript
date:Fri, 16 Sep 2016 08:31:11 GMT
etag:W/"67515ed3d4b367595d2bffec7957e091"
last-modified:Thu, 18 Aug 2016 14:42:58 GMT
server:NetDNA-cache/2.2
status:200
x-amz-id-2:NyXyLH0T3oam8vXdxwaWXnVO6z2zI7sAnwh3Z+hmkgfbUc5x8dGsJOAajOZvkLCZC6FbnHcAWtU=
x-amz-request-id:C5CAA9C95369D6C0
x-cache:HIT
Request Headers
:authority:use.fontawesome.com
:method:GET
:path:/f7710.js
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
cache-control:no-cache
origin:http://0.0.0.0:8080
pragma:no-cache
referer:http://0.0.0.0:8080/login?redirect=%2Fprofile
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Yeah, that's my localhost. Doesn't work there or on our webserver.

Comment: That's not the real url, I'm not posting my keys publicly.

Comment: There are special reserved IPs, 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1, that mean the same as localhost. They're just shortcuts.

Comment: I don't want to turn this into a discussion about 0.0.0.0 - but `The IP address 0.0.0.0 has several special meanings on computer networks. It cannot be used as a general-purpose device address, however.` - http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/g/0_0_0_0_ip-address.htm

Comment: `That's not the real url, I'm not posting my keys publicly.` - good point - what do you see in the response headers from use.fontawesome.com - especially the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - oh, wait, you don't get that header - strange

Comment: are there any requests for `..../css/font-awesome-css.min.css` and `..../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2` - they are the ones that need CORS headers

Comment: No requests for the fonts are made - only the .js file, which dies.  But if I remove the `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes everything works fine. It still doesn't return an `allow-origin` type header but my page loads without error. So I have a workaround, but I don't know why it works...

Comment: `It still doesn't return an allow-origin type header` - it doesn't need to for the js file

Comment: so stop using that CDN! that's all. Use this instead: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-AIodEDkC8V/bHBkfyxzolUMw57jeQ9CauwhVW6YJ9CA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />`